# Python Global Variables Between Classes

Tags: python, class, global-variables, global

I haven't done much with global and I was wondering how I can make the functions and variables inside a class global. I was trying to test global between classes using fonts and functions. If anyone can point out where i am going wrong, it would be very helpful.

Global.py

```
#Fonts
#Common Functions
import tkFont

class Global():
    def __init__(self):
        global f,f1,f2,enter,leave
        f = tkFont.Font(name='f',size=14, weight='bold')
        f1 = tkFont.Font(name='f1',size=12, weight='bold')
        f2 = tkFont.Font(name='f2', underline=True,size=12, weight='bold')

    def enter(self,event):
            event.widget.config(font='f2')
    def leave(self,event):
            event.widget.config(font='f1')
```

LoginFrame.py

```
from Tkinter import *
from Global import *

class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        Global()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self.master,bg='black',width=800,height=500,bd=5,relief=GROOVE)
        self.user_lbl = Label(self.frame, text='User', bg='black', fg='white',font='f1')
        self.user_lbl.bind('<Enter>',enter), self.user_lbl.bind('<Leave>',leave)

        self.pw_lbl = Label(self.frame, text='Password', bg='black', fg='white',font='f2')
        self.pw_lbl.bind('<Enter>',enter), self.pw_lbl.bind('<Leave>',leave)

    def packWidgets(self):
        self.frame.grid_propagate(0), self.frame.grid(row=1)
        self.user_lbl.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
        self.pw_lbl.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W)


root=Tk()
loginFrame=LoginFrame(root)
loginFrame.createWidgets()
loginFrame.packWidgets()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your question?  You just posted some code without saying what you want it to do.  Give a specific example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```
def __init__(self,master):
    self.master=master
    Global()
```

Global() is just created and not assigned.  Global's `__init__` calls

```
global f,f1,f2,enter,leave
```

But this defines the scope, not a 'global variable'.

One option is to do the following

```
class Globals():
    f = tkFont.Font(name='f',size=14, weight='bold')
    f1 = tkFont.Font(name='f1',size=12, weight='bold')
    f2 = tkFont.Font(name='f2', underline=True,size=12, weight='bold')
```

or simply define them by themselves

```
 f = tkFont.Font(name='f',size=14, weight='bold')
 f1 = tkFont.Font(name='f1',size=12, weight='bold')
 f2 = tkFont.Font(name='f2', underline=True,size=12, weight='bold')
```

and then use globals in your function.  You don't need the keyword `global` unless you are making an assignment

```
self.pw_lbl = Label(...,f)
```

Comment: Are you basically just telling OP not to use `global`?

Comment: @Marcin - no, I'm commenting that it's odd to have a `Globals` class that also uses the globals keyword, much like you did and to demonstrate that he can use class-level variables within a class if he wants to organize them there.   If there's a reason to define  constant-like globals from within a class (e.g., on initialization), I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't done much with global and I was wondering how I can make the
>   functions and variables inside a class global.

You can't. Inside a method, you can declare a variable as global, and assignments to it will be to the global variable.

There isn't any other level of globalness.

Of course, you wouldn't want to do this, because the point of classes is to avoid global state, and to keep shared state encapsulated.